# cakePHP - conditional save, can it be done?

Tags: cakephp, save, conditional-statements, undo

Scenario:
The method in the controller that saves the data is using some complex calculations on the results of the first `Model->save()` call.
The result then saved in a related-associated model. sometimes it fails..

Is there a built-in way to do it with cake, which will delete the first record when the second save has failed?

Comment: Are you familiar with Model callback functions? You might be able to use them to come up with something. [reference here](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1048/Callback-Methods)

Comment: nope, going there now. thanks

Comment: They saved me a lot of trouble, and easily allow you to push off a bunch of logic from your controller into the models.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you absolutely can't do these calculations in the app without first saving into the database, use [Transactions](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1633/Transactions):

```
$dbo = $this->Model->getDataSource();
$dbo->begin($this->Model);

$this->Model->save(...);

/* here be dragons */

if (/* success */) {
    $dbo->commit($this->Model);
} else {
    $dbo->rollback($this->Model);
}
```

That requires that you use a database *and storage engine* that supports transactions, like [MySQL's InnoDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-transaction-model.html).

Comment: Just the thing that i am looking for! tnx

Comment: All mythical serpent references get +1'd immediately.